# Underline Rows in Only One Column of Multirow Multicolumn Table with ONLY Two Columns

Tags: latex

I am trying to make a multicolumn, multirow table with two columns and 5 rows. I want each row in the second column only underlined. Obviously, \bottomrule underlines both columns, as does \hline. \hline also throws a \noalign error. Neither \cline{2-2}, \cline{2-3}, nor \cline{2} work. Both \cline{2-2} and \cline{2} underline both columns, and \cline{2-3} throws an Extra alignment tab error.

I have tried many different package combinations without luck, and I want the final document to be simple for school teachers to use (Grades 1 - 12.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[text={7.25in,10in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} 
%------------------------------% 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H] 
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Learning Standard(s): }\begin{minipage}{5.5in} CCSS # \end{minipage}\\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lesson Objective(s): }\begin{minipage}{5.5in}\par The learner                                        will be able to . . . \end{minipage}\\
        \bottomrule 

        %------problem begins here-----              

        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Lesson Activities}}}\begin{minipage}        
        {6in}Demonstration:\end{minipage}\\ 
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\begin{minipage}{6in}Guided Practice: \end{minipage}\\ 
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\begin{minipage}{6in}Individual Practice:\end{minipage}\\ 
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\begin{minipage}{6in}Formative Assessment: \end{minipage}\\ 
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}\begin{minipage}{6in}Other/Notes: \end{minipage}\\ 

        %-----problem ends here-----         
        \toprule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lesson Resources: }\begin{minipage}{5.5in} \end{minipage}\\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lesson Close: }\begin{minipage}{5.5in} \end{minipage}\\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am expecting something like the following.

```
_______________________
|     |_______________|
|     |_______________|
|     |_______________|
|     |_______________|
|_____|_______________|
```

Answer (score 0):

- you must not use `#` in your table without escaping it
- `latin1` input encoding is most probably wrong. Double check if your file really is encoded in latin1, this would be very unusual this century
- don't specify a driver to hyperref - in the best case it is unnecessary because hyperref will automatically detect it, in all other case it will simply be wrong
- if you want to have the rule only in one column, then you should actually use more than one column and not bake everything together into a single column
- have a look at the `tabularray` package, this would make your table way less painful

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[text={7.25in,10in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[]{hyperref} 
%------------------------------% 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H] 
        \begin{tabular}{p{1in}l}
        \toprule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Learning Standard(s): }\begin{minipage}{5.5in} CCSS \# \end{minipage}\\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lesson Objective(s): }\begin{minipage}{5.5in}\par The learner                                        will be able to . . . \end{minipage}\\
        \bottomrule 

        %------problem begins here-----              

        \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Lesson Activities}} & Demonstration:\\ \cmidrule{2-2}
        & Guided Practice: \\ \cmidrule{2-2}
        & Individual Practice:\\ \cmidrule{2-2}
        & Formative Assessment: \\ \cmidrule{2-2}
        & Other/Notes: \\ 

        %-----problem ends here-----         
        \toprule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lesson Resources: }\begin{minipage}{5.5in} \end{minipage}\\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lesson Close: }\begin{minipage}{5.5in} \end{minipage}\\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The use of latin1 is because there will be a need for teachers to use accented letters, for example, ä or ü. As far as the multiple columns are concerned, I have no option. That is how the document owner needs it. These teachers have a format required by their district. Although, when I compile it, it looks fairly close to what I need. The only issue is I need the 5 parts of the lesson plan separated from "Lesson Activities" by a vertical line.

Comment: The encoding you specify should match the encoding of your .tex file. Almost certainly, it is uff8.